# Lazard's $\Gamma_n(f)$ as cocycle

Tags: group-cohomology, abstract-algebra, formal-groups, obstruction-theory

In Michel Lazard's "Commutative Formal Groups" Springer Lecture Notes, he defines an operator on a polynomial 3-cochain $f$ denoted $\Gamma_n(f)$, which defines as the $n^{th}$ homogeneous piece of the difference $f(f(x,y),z)-f(x,f(y,z))$.  He later notes (in equation 5.10) that $\Gamma_n(f)$ is always a cocycle, that is, $\delta\Gamma_n(f)=0$ for any $n$ and any symmetric $f$, where $\delta(g)(x,y,z,w)=g(y,z,w)-g(x+y,z,w)+g(x,y+z,w)-g(x,y,z+w)+g(x,y,z).$  He claims that proving that such a thing is a cocycle is easy (even for non-symmetric polynomials) and says he will leave the proof to the reader.  I have tried to prove it repeatedly and failed, and am worried I'm just being stupid here. I've basically been writing down a lot of polynomials and trying to show things cancel, which is perhaps a bit naive. Does anyone know how this proof goes? We're basically showing that a certain obstruction is always a cocycle.

Comment: You have to use the hypothesis that $f$ is an $(n-1)$-bud (in Lazard's terminology); not sure what you mean by "polynomial 3-cochain", but if you don't use the $(n-1)$-bud hypothesis then you're trying to prove something false.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to mention that as part of the hypothesis. I certainly have been using that.

Comment: @user36938 I probably shouldn't say polynomial 3-cochain, I just meant that it's not yet clear that it's a cocycle, so it's a cochain.

Comment: But you put the word "cochain" in a place that refers to $f$, not $\Gamma_n(f)$, so it is confusing. Do you understand why it works when $f$ is an $n$-bud?

Comment: @user36938 Hm okay, yeah, no I agree, I have some sort of strange terminology there.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Hazewinkel's book "Formal groups and applications" to see if whatever you ultimately want may be proved there in a more complete form?